# How to handle the authentication flow when using Google sign in in my Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0, google-authentication

I am planning to use Google sign in for my Chrome extension. I came across the following docs:

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in

From what I understand, clicking on the auth button opens up another webpage, and then if the user authenticates the app, then they are redirected back to the page. Now, what if I want to do this from my Chrome extension that can run on my webpage/domain. What would be the workflow for authenticating then using Google sign in?

Comment: Extensions can use [`chrome.identity` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/identity)

Comment: Have you checked this [documentation - User Authentication](https://developers.chrome.com/apps/app_identity)? It says from the User interaction that if you invoke the API in interactive mode, **the user is shown a sign in and/or approval UI when necessary**.